# How can I change this code so that it doesn't reference the workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

How can I change this piece of code to eliminate the reference to the workbook? It works properly but the reference means I can't change the name of the workbook without also having to change the code.

```
w1 = Application.Run("'Book1'!TdbTwbtoGrains", Z, db1, wb1)
w2 = Application.Run("Book1'!TdbTwbtoGrains", Z, db2, wb2)
```

This code is in a module within Book1.

Also posted on Excel Forum: https://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/1303243-change-syntax-to-eliminate-xla-file.html#post5263762

Comment: Take out the workbook part...

Comment: Probably useful detail that `Book1` is an add-in.

Comment: Does your VBA project reference the Book1 add-in? If so, all you need is `w1 = TdbTwbtoGrains(Z, db1, wb1)` and `w2 = TdbTwbtoGrains(Z, db2, wb2)` (consider renaming that procedure/macro - it desperately wants vowels)

Comment: Thanks @braX. I just removed the 'Book1'! part and it seems to compile.